# React изменение state определённого объетка

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как изменить state только определённых объектов? Код создаёт столько объектов сколько их подаётся из БД с помощью метода map.

```
{ items.map((item, index) => (
    <div className="col"> <Button onClick={less}>-</Button><a href="#" className="border">{quantity}</a><Button onClick={more}>+</Button> </div>
    ))}
```

Ниже код React, он содержит логику изменения числа с помощью кнопок + и -

```
let [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1)
    function less(){
    setQuantity(quantity = quantity - 1)
  }
  function more(){
    setQuantity(quantity = quantity + 1)
  }
```

Но проблема в том, что если нажать на кнопку, то событие будет происходить для всех объектов тогда как очевидно нужно чтобы оно происходило только для одного. Как это можно устроить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Логично было бы для каждого item хранить свой quantity (хоть прям item.quantity) и с ним "работать"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот кусок можно использовать как отдельный компонент.

```js
<div className="col"> <Button onClick={less}>-</Button><a href="#" className="border">{quantity}</a><Button onClick={more}>+</Button> </div>
```

```js
export const Column = () => {
    let [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1)

    const less = () => {
       setQuantity(quantity--)
    }

    const more = () => {
       setQuantity(quantity++)
    }

  return (
     <div className="col">
        <Button onClick={less}>-</Button>
        <a href="#" className="border">{quantity}</a>
        <Button onClick={more}>+</Button> 
     </div>
  )
}
```

```js
{items.map((item, index) => (
    <Column />
    ))}
```